# How to get day from Week

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL server, I can get everyday with select, but now I want to select all the last weekday a in every week based on Today. It means, when today is Friday, then I need all Friday in certain period.

This is what I expected (Today: 2018/30/11):

```
2018/30/11
2018/23/11
2018/16/11
2018/9/11
2018/2/11
2018/26/10
2018/19/10
```

Comment: What is your RDBMS? Oracle, MS Sql etc?

Comment: could it be you mean 2018/26/10 and 2018/19/10

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: The expected result appears to contain more than a weeks worth of dates. Also, what is the format of the dates being returned? Could you explain what you're trying to achieve and what you've tried already?

Comment: Dates have no format, they are binary values.  `last 7 day a week by Today` what does that mean? What results do you expect? Why not `someField >= DATEADD(DAY,-7,GETDATE())` ?

Comment: As for the *strings* in this question, they use an unusual form. Dates are binary values. Formats apply only when they are converted to strings for display puproses. This means that *your application* specifies how to display the `datetime` or `date` values returned by the database. If you want the *database* to format the strings, use the `FORMAT` function

Comment: Wait... looks like 7 Fridays to me (if the last two rows are Oct instead of Nov). Is that correct?

Comment: sorry guys i have edited :D its sql sever btw, i also posted my current SQL below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that last 2 rows from your expected results are from **October**, here is how to get these:

```
select DATEADD(week, Numbers.Number, cast(getdate() as date))
from (values(0), (-1), (-2), (-3), (-4), (-5), (-6)) Numbers(Number)
order by 1 desc
```

With the [Table Value Constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) we get a table `Numbers` with one column `Number` and values from 0 to -6. Then you add this number of weeks to the current date to get your desired result.

Comment: What do you assume the OP's question is? Given how badly worded it is, it could mean "return the last 7 days" or ... what did you guess?

Comment: Each date is a week before the other. So last 2 rows should be 2018/26/10 and 2018/19/10.

Comment: You mean the OP wants to generate a sequence of the last 7 days?

Comment: he seems to want the dates of the last 7 weeks, starting with today, he wants the date 0, 7,14,21,28...days ago.  His '11' on the earliest date was possibly supposed to be a 10 - so this code seems to do it

Answer (score 3):

I think you want to retrieve records with a date not older than 7 days.
This should do the trick:

```
SELECT *
WHERE YourDateColumn >= DATEADD(DAY,-7,GETDATE())
```

Comment: its not my expected :(

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps. where start and end dates are the dates for which you want to get the dates between

```
DECLARE @weeks INT,
        @start_date DATETIME = '2018/10/01',
        @end_date DATETIME = '2018/11/30',
        @date DATETIME,
        @day INT = 7 

CREATE TABLE #temp (result_date DATETIME)

SELECT @weeks = DATEDIFF(week, @start_date, @end_date) 

SELECT @weeks

WHILE @weeks <> 0
BEGIN 
    SET @day = @day + 7 

    INSERT INTO #temp
        SELECT dateadd(day, -@day, GETDATE())

    SET @weeks = @weeks - 1
END 

SELECT * FROM #temp
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried using below code.

```
declare @today datetime = cast(floor(cast(GETDATE() as float)) as smalldatetime)
declare @i int = 1
while @i < 8
    begin
        print(@today)
        set @today = DATEADD(DAY,-7,@today)
        set @i = @i + 1
    end
```